# 'Is Displayed' to active voice

Tags: grammar, passive-voice, active-voice

I got below error while writing content for a ebook. I am using grammar verification tool online and it throwed the below error message "This sentence appears to be written in the passive voice. Consider writing in the active voice. "
What will be the correct voice conversion option?

My content:

> 'the output is displayed in the browser with links to all developed web pages.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rephrase. "The output" is the object of the verb "displays" in the active voice. Try, "The browser displays the output with links to all developed web pages."

Answer (score 1):

"Appears"

come into sight; become visible or noticeable, typically without visible agent or apparent cause.